# php multi-dimensional array help needed

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this array (shortened for this question), and I need to extract the country_code ("AF" and "AL" in this demo) in order to insert the region info into a table based on the country.

How do I get the country code while iterating the array and is this the correct way to do this?

```
$countries = array("AF" => array("BDS" => "Badakhshan",
                                 "BDG" => "Badghis",
                                 "BGL" => "Baghlan",
                                 "BAL" => "Balkh",
                                 "BAM" => "Bamian",
                                 "DAY" => "Daykondi"),
                   "AL" => array("BR" => "Berat",
                                 "BU" => "Bulqizë",
                                 "DL" => "Delvinë",
                                 "DV" => "Devoll",
                                 "DI" => "Dibër",
                                 "DR" => "Durrës",
                                 "EL" => "Elbasan",
                                 "FR" => "Fier")
);

foreach ($countries as $country) {
  $country_code = $country[]; // How do I get the country code here?
  foreach ($country as $region_code => $region_name) {
    // insert region info into table
  } // foreach ($country as $region_code => $region_name)
} // foreach ($countries as $country)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is setup with `key => value` pairs, meaning you have a value, and an identifier for that value.

```
$myArray = array( "Key" => "Value" );
```

Or, in the case of your code:

```
$myArray = array( "Country Code" => array( "Region" => "Codes" ) );
```

If you wish to get the key while looping, use the following syntax:

```
foreach ( $myArray as $key => $value ) {
  echo $key; // "Country Code"
  foreach ( $value as $region_key => $region_code ) {
    echo $region_key; // Region
  }
}
```

Now you're able to access the identifer with each iteration.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: MB34, this is the same thing i posted. and the same thing the other person posted

Comment: the exact equivalent but using while loop http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164501/1165128

Comment: [quote]this is the same thing i posted.[/quote] It wasn't either. It showed how to get the country_code and yours did not originally. I stand by my accepting Jonathan's post as answer.

Comment: mine did show how, i said in my post "code and rcode will have the two region codes"

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($countries as $code => $list) {
 foreach($list as $rcode => $name) {

 }
}
```

code and rcode will have the two region codes

i Mentioned in my comment, that that was the only way, but, i stand corrected

```
foreach($countries as $country)
{
        $code = array_keys($countries, $country);
        $code = $code[0];
}
```

might get you what you are looking for, super weird way to do it tho, and i dont suggest using it. The first method is better

Comment: Ignored my question "How do I get the country code while iterating the array"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using it already in the nested loop:

```
foreach ($countries as $country_code => $country) {
    foreach ($country as $region_code => $region_name) {
        // foobar
    }
}
```

The variable `$country_code` then holds the country code.

Comment: Ignored my question "How do I get the country code while iterating the array"

Comment: No I did not. Sorry, I thought it was obvious that the variable `$country_code` would hold the country code. I edited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($country = current($countries)){
    while($region = current($country)){
        echo "region:".$region."(".key($country).")"." country:".key($countries);
        next($country);
    }
    next($countries);
}
```